# JavaScript PromiseAll allSettled does not catch the rejected

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a sns lambda function that returns void (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html). This event orderId and one message'status: success' are what I'm publishing. I check if the 'orderId' exists in my data database in the sns subscription lambda event. If it already exists, update the database; if it doesn't, console error it.

I created an integration test in which I transmit a random 'uuid' that isn't a valid 'orderId,' but it appears that my promise doesn't capture the'rejected'. It should show in console error `failed to find order..`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. **Also My promise syntax looks complicated, is there any neat way, I can do it. Thank you in advance**

**This is sns event, which listen the publishing**

```js
interface PromiseFulfilledResult<T> {
  status: "fulfilled" | "rejected";
  value: T;
}

const parseOrdersFromSns = (event: SNSEvent) => {
  try {
    return event.Records.flatMap((r) => JSON.parse(r.Sns.Message))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('New order from SNS failed at parsing orders', { event }, error)
    return []
  }
}

export const handlerFn = async (event: SNSEvent): Promise<void> => {
 const orders = parseOrdersFromSns(event)

  if (orders.length === 0) return
  const existingOrdersPromiseResult = await Promise.allSettled(
    orders.map(
      async (o) => await findOrderStateNode(tagOrderStateId(o.orderId))
    )
  ); //  This returns of data if the order exsiit other it will return undefined 

  const existingOrders = existingOrdersPromiseResult // should returns arrays of data
    .filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled")
    .map(
      (o) =>
        (
          o as PromiseFulfilledResult<
            TaggedDatabaseDocument<
              OrderStateNode,
              TaggedOrderStateId,
              TaggedOrderStateId
            >
          >
        ).value
    );

  const failedOrders = existingOrdersPromiseResult.filter( // should stop the opeartion if the data is exsit
    ({ status }) => status === "rejected"
  );
  failedOrders.forEach((failure) => {
    console.error("failed to find order", { failure });
  });

  const updateOrder = await Promise.all(
    existingOrders.map((o) => {
      const existingOrderId = o?.pk as TaggedOrderStateId;
      console.log({ existingOrderId }); // Return Undefined 
    })
  );

  return updateOrder;
};
```

**this is my test suite**

```js
describe('Creating and updating order', () => {
  integrationTest(
    'Creating and updating the order',
    async (correlationId: string) => {
      CorrelationIds.set('x-correlation-id', correlationId)

      const createdOrder = await createNewOrder(correlationId) // This create random order

      if (!createdOrder.id) {
        fail('order id is not defined')
      }

      const order = await getOrder(createdOrder.id)

      // Add new order to table
      await initializeOrderState([order])

      const exisitingOrder = await findOrderStateNode(tagOrderStateId(order.id))

      if (!exisitingOrder) fail(`Could not existing order with this orderId: ${order.id}`)

      const event = {
        Records: [
          {
            Sns: {
              Message: JSON.stringify([
                {
                  orderId: uuid(), // random order it
                  roundName,
                  startTime,
                },
                {
                  orderId: order.id,
                  roundName,
                  startTime,
                },
                {
                  orderId: uuid(),
                  roundName,
                  startTime,
                },
              ]),
            },
          },
        ],
      } as SNSEvent

      await SnsLambda(event)

      const updateOrderState = await findOrderStateNode(tagOrderStateId(order.id))

      expect(updateOrderState?.status).toEqual('success')
  
    },
  )
})
```

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what is happening that is unexpected. Is `failedOrders` not what you expected? Do you not see the `console.error()` lines in the `forEach()`?

Comment: sorry for my english. Yes, it does not show the  console.error

Comment: _Syntactically_  `orders.map()` argument seems overly complicated -  you might try `orders.map(   o=> findOrderStateNode(tagOrderStateId(o.orderId) ))`.  It might also be worth logging `existingOrdersPromiseResult` to see if it has any rejected promises in it, or get clues as to why it doesn't.